# разбор ответа геокоде при прямом геокодировнии

Tags: json, promise

Опишу вопрос на примере задачи: есть список улиц, у которых есть уникальные id. нужно получить информацию о них через геокодер.  При этом нужно сохранить соответствие id и ответа геокодера. Т.е. в идеале я делаю массив, где ключ - id, значение - адрес, прогоняю его через геокодер, и вместо адреса кладу разобранный ответ. В своих попытках я исходил из  примера https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode . Проблема 2 - к примеру есть цель дополнить информацию о геообхектах, которые мы ищем в геокодере, информацией из ответа. к примеру нормальное название улицы, район, город, область. В ответе геокодера в разделе options это можно найти, НО - как добыть что то из опций - не понятно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как построить вызов кодера так, чтобы потом получить в ответ из промиса объект, или адекватный результат как return, как заставить его выполняться последовательно, и как получить по отдельности название улицы, города, номер дома...
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Немогу посмотреть пример, но чем не подходит:

```
var street = [{id: 1, name: '#1'}, {id: 1, name: '#2'}] 
 street.forEach(function(item) {
 getGeoInfo(item.id).then(function(result) {
  item.name = result.name;
  item.city = result.city;
  //etc.
 })
})
```